# Formula for monotonic increasing functions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f:[n]\to \mathcal{P}([k])$ be a strongly monotonic increasing with respect to the subset relation if $\forall i,j\in [n]$ if $i\le j$ then $f(i)\subsetneq f(j)$. Let $a_{n,k}$ be the number of such functions. Find the value of $a_{n,k}$ for $n>k+1$ using pigeon hole principle.

not sure how to start. I solved it using inclusion-exclusion but that's not the way they are asking for here. why is the condition $n>k+1$ relevant? any hint would help.

Comment: Hi :) Can you find any strongly monotonic increasing function $f\colon [n]\to\mathcal P([k])$, if $n>k+1$? Search for one. There are not many of them. Is there an argument, that there is no such function, when $n$ is much larger than $k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the chain $f(1) \subsetneq f(2) \subsetneq… \subsetneq f(n) $. Each of these subsets of $[k]$ must have at least one more element than the preceding one.